# Project.properties for Ant Build cant find properties for play licensing

Tags: android, ant, google-play-services

I have this in my properties file:

```
# This file is automatically generated by Android Tools.
# Do not modify this file -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE ERASED!
#
# This file must be checked in Version Control Systems.
#
# To customize properties used by the Ant build system edit
# "ant.properties", and override values to adapt the script to your
# project structure.
#
# To enable ProGuard to shrink and obfuscate your code, uncomment this (available      properties: sdk.dir, user.home):
#proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt

# Project target.
target=Google Inc.:Google APIs:8
android.library.reference.1=..\\library
android.library.reference.3=../../../../../android/extras/google/play_licensing/library
android.library.reference.2=../downloader_library
```

My Google library is located at c:\android, yet, for some reason, I keep getting this error when trying to build with ant:

```
BUILD FAILED
c:\android\tools\ant\build.xml:577: ../../../adt-bundle-windows-x86/sdk/extras/g
oogle/play_licensing/licencing_library resolve to a path with no project.propert
ies file for project C:\Joeys fun projects\ags\otgdy\OtGDY_v100\downloader_libra
ry

Total time: 1 second
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: I'm not in a position to check the SDK at the moment but I can't help noticing that you have two different spellings of licencing and licensing in the error message.  It might be nothing but worth checking.

Comment: Yes. There was a spelling mistake there. I changed it, but still did not solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If using any other developer outside of the android sdk you must have ANT build tool installed via your command line.
1) download the apache ANT plugin - [ANT](http://ant.apache.org/bindownload.cgi)
2) unzip
3) open sdk and add path to plugin for import

If using the android sdk go here for documentation on how to update the ANT plugin: [developer android](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/eclipse-adt.html)

Could be that you need to add a path to the sdk for you ~/.profile if on mac, Windows 7 would be your environment path

Have you setup your workspace correctly? The build output signifies to me that the setup is missing a module or plugin. You might try updating as much as possible and checking the docs for any key plugins you might be missing.

Comment: Yep, already did all that. I have a path setup for the NDk, the SDK, The Java dir and for Ant.